# How do i array.push from inside PubNub function to Angular scope?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, nested, pubnub, nested-function

**My HTML**

`ng-app` and `ng-controller` are specified in markup earlier

```
<div class="statusEntry" ng-repeat="statusInput in statusInputs">
 <span class="userName"> a </span>                
 <span  class="statusMsg"> b </span>                
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
app.controller('globalCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
//someWork
pubnub.subscribe({
channel: "statuses",
callback:
function (data) {

    splitData = data.split(';');
    prepData = '{'+splitData[0]+','+splitData[1]+'}';
    statusInputs.push(prepData);
}
});
```

When I push the data no new object appears.
Angular doesnt get the data, even if i prepend `statusInputs` with `$scope`.

It looks like i need to pass the data to root scope from nested functions, i dont know how.

Comment: try angular.extend($scope,MYService)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Initialize the array when you first get to your controller:

```
$scope.statusInputs = [];
```

and in your callback function change:

```
statusInputs.push(prepData);
```

to

```
$scope.statusInputs.push(prepData);
//also, because pubnub is defined outside of angular
//call $scope.$apply() to force angular to recognize 
//the change on the scope
$scope.$apply()
```

Basically you are declaring an array on your scope, which your UI will use, and then upon each callback you are appending items into that bound array.

Comment: Thanks, this does push the data correctly. Would you by any chance know why new object appears not immediately, but after i type a letter into `input` ? Do i need to somehow refresh ?

Comment: I would presume that pubnub has nothing to do w/ angular and as a result this change is not triggering a digest cycle. After the push call, add a call to $scope.$apply()